# VBA Dictionary behaving wildly

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am having a lot of trouble understanding the output for the below code snippet

```
Sub TestDictionary
    Dim d as dictionary
    set d = new dictionary

    debug.print d.count
    debug.print d(1)
    debug.print d.count

End Sub
```

The above snippet gives the o/p as below

```
0
            `I presume this line being the empty string
1
```

I expected subscript out of range for line `debug.print d(1)`, But to my horror it returned an empty string.

Can anyone enlighten me why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the correct behavior. The `Scripting.Dictionary` object is made in such a way that `dict(x) = something` either assigns to an existing entry or creates the entry if none.

Also reading `dict(x)` creates the entry with an `empty Variant` if no entry already exists.

This is how the `Scripting.Dictionary` is specified, and this behavior is useful in many situations.

Notice that you can change this behavior in your code, by simply checking if the entry exists before accessing it:

```
If dict.exists(x) then
    do something with dict(x)...
End If
```

So your code above could be written this way:

```
Sub TestDictionary
    Dim d as dictionary
    set d = new dictionary

    debug.print d.count
    if d.Exists("1") then Debug.Print d("1")
    debug.print d.count
End Sub
```

Also notice that **the key is a String**. You dont expect to have the integer as an index like an array. d(1) is just an entry that could be placed anywhere, with the key string `"1"`.

Answer (score 5):

It's because with `d(1)` you're directly accessing the dictionary item corresponding to "1" key and if there's no such key then VBScript creates it under the hood. That's why the subsequent `d.count` returns `1`

You can have some deeper testing as follows:

```
Sub TestDictionary()
    Dim d As Dictionary
    Set d = New Dictionary

    Debug.Print d.count     '--> returns 0
    Debug.Print d.keys(0)   '--> returns an error, there are no keys, yet
    Debug.Print d(4)        '--> returns "", i.e. the not defined item associated with the newly created key (which is "4")
    Debug.Print d.keys(0)   '--> returns "4", i.e. the first (and only) dictionary key
    Debug.Print d.keys(1)   '--> returns an error, since there's only one item in the dictionary
    Debug.Print d.Exists(1) '--> returns False, since there's no "1" key in the dictionary
    Debug.Print d.Exists(4) '--> returns True, since there's a "4" key in the dictionary
    Debug.Print d.count     '--> 1, since the third statement created a dictionary item

End Sub
```

Bottom Line: Use `Dictionary` `Count` property to know if it has any item and `Exist(key)` property if you're looking for a specific key